# Getting Apache and mod_wsgi to run Anaconda's Python 3.6.0 for a flask app

Tags: python, apache, flask, anaconda, mod-wsgi

I have a virtual server with Ubuntu 16.04 and a LAMP stack installed. I also have the latest Anaconda installed and set as my default Python. I have created a basic app similar to that in the following tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps?

When I return `sys.version` instead of the hello message it returns python 2.7 when viewing it in the browser. My question is how do I get this to use the same python installation as my system's default, the Anaconda Python 3.6.0?

Comment: Did you compile mod_wsgi from source code against the Anaconda Python installation? Or are you using a system packages mod_wsgi? You must compile from source code yourself.